# numpy.float64' object is not callable - hyperparameter tuning

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to do hyperparameter tuning and every time I run this code.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = {'C':[0,1,1,100,1000], 'kernel':['rbf','poly','sigmoid','linear'],'degree':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
grid =GridSearchCV(svc.sc(),param_grid)
grid.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I get this error

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-74de9eeb3cae> in <module>
      3 
      4 param_grid = {'C':[0,1,1,100,1000], 'kernel':['rbf','poly','sigmoid','linear'],'degree':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
----> 5 grid =GridSearchCV(svc.sc(),param_grid)
      6 grid.fit(X_train,y_train)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Any idea what to do? Also `svc.sc` is the way defined the model.

Comment: Welcome to SO; for the next time, please take a minute to see how to properly format your code snippets (done it for you now).

Comment: Please post the full error trace. And what is `svc.sc()`?

Comment: Please **show** how exactly you have defined your `svc.sc` model. Not here - edit & update your post.

Answer (score 1):

What is `svc.sc()`? Either way, you're probably not meant to call it at that point, just pass it as the callback to `GridSearchCV`, i.e. drop the parentheses:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(svc.sc, param_grid)
```

Comment: Hi there,  so basically I wrote the model for svm like this:                                                    
svc = SVC(gamma='auto')
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)
svc.sc = svc.score(X_test, y_test)
svc.sc

Comment: Also I got this error when I make the changes.                                                      

TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, 0.9412915851272016 was passed. Thanks

Comment: @IvanChowdhury then it should be `grid = GridSearchCV(svc, param_grid)`. You should pass a *model* to `GridSearchCV`, not a number; that's why we have been asking from the very beginning to post how you have defined the model (in your post, *not* in the comments).